# How to lock data in postgres the optimal way

Tags: sql, postgresql, locks

I have these two functions that act as a mutex lock and unlock:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_config (guildid_in int8, key_in varchar) RETURNS jsonb AS $$
    DECLARE d JSONB;
    BEGIN
        WHILE (SELECT locked FROM guild_options WHERE guildid = guildid_in AND key = key_in) LOOP END LOOP;
        UPDATE guild_options SET locked = true WHERE guildid = guildid_in AND key = key_in;
        SELECT data INTO d FROM guild_options WHERE guildid = guildid_in AND key = key_in ;
        REtURN d;
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION set_config (guildid_in int8, key_in varchar, data_in jsonb) RETURNS void AS $$
    BEGIN
        UPDATE guild_options SET locked = false, data = data_in WHERE guildid = guildid_in AND key = key_in;
    END;
    $$ LANGUAGE  plpgsql;
```

The reason I have these two functions is because I don't want data race between different client overwriting data and so on, this allow me to lock a piece of data, modifying it then unlock for the other clients to read/update. I didn't go with postgres locks (Table locks, row locks, advisory locks) as I need the ability to lock over multiple transaction and because I use a database pool in my program I can't use advisory locks as there are multiple sessions connected to the database at once and I don't control which one lock/unlock

Is there a better way to do this (like better polling)?

Answer (score 0):

You "need the ability to lock over multiple transaction". That is exactly what Postgres locks do. Advisory locks can be taken at the transaction or session level. You may also want to look as [Serializable Isolation Level](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.2/xact-serializable.html).  
BTW: Your functions do not accomplish what you expect. In `get_config` you update locked column to True, but *no other session see this until you commit*. Now if this process part of a much larger and only partially complete transaction a commit here commits everything done so far if the overall transaction fails later you have committed part of a transaction.  Even it you do commit after the update there is still a chance another transaction gets in between the Update and the Commit (slim but not 0). Same applies the `set_config` function.